# settimeout is not working because of React-bootstrap validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, axios, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to set form validation in React-bootstrap.
I've just written code in accordance with React-bootstrap document.
https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/forms/#forms-validation
I confirmed validation is activated and data is changed when I push submit button.
[image]
But only setTimeout method is not working because of adding React-bootstrap validation code.
I couldn't find where I missed and should fix.
Could you tell me the differences between my code and document.
Also, I add comments to my code to make clearly.
PS: I debugged my code. I found that that code was skipped.
I am investigating causes now.

```
.then(response => {
                if (response.data != null) {
                    alert('編集完了！')
                    window.setTimeout(() => {
                        history.push("/")
                    }, 1000)
                }
            })
```

Before adding code

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Card, Form, Button, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import { Copyright } from './Copyright';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faList, faHome, faClipboardCheck } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

export const EditData = (props) => {


    const history = useHistory()
    const id = props.listNo;
    const [dataOne, setDataOne] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:8080/action/edit/" + id).then((response) =>
            setDataOne(response.data)
        )
    }, [])

    const handleChange = event => {
        setDataOne({ ...dataOne, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    };

    const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const list = {
            listNo: dataOne.listNo,
            softwareName: dataOne.softwareName,
            saiyouDate: dataOne.saiyouDate,
            version: dataOne.version,
            shubetu: dataOne.shubetu,
            licenseManage: dataOne.licenseManage,
            youto: dataOne.youto,
            bikou: dataOne.bikou,
            authorizer: dataOne.authorizer,
            approvalDate: dataOne.approvalDate,
            url: dataOne.url
        }

        axios.post("http://localhost:8080/action/edit/contents", list)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data != null) {
                    alert('編集完了！')
                    window.setTimeout(() => {
                        history.push("/")
                    }, 1000)
                }
            })
    };



    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container">
                <Card>
                    <Card.Header className="text-center" style={{ backgroundColor: '#75A9FF', color: '#FFF' }}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faList} />使用許可ソフトウェアリスト
                    </Card.Header>
                    <Form id="listFormId" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                        <Form.Control
                            required
                            type="hidden"
                            name="listNo"
                            value={dataOne.listNo || ""}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />

                        <Card.Body>
                            <Form.Row>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>ソフトウェア名</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        type="text"
                                        name="softwareName"
                                        value={dataOne.softwareName || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                    />
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Form.Row>
                            <Form.Row>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>採用日</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        type="text"
                                        name="saiyouDate"
                                        value={dataOne.saiyouDate || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange} />
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>バージョン</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        type="text"
                                        name="version"
                                        value={dataOne.version || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                    />
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Form.Row>
                            <Form.Row>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>種別</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        type="text"
                                        name="shubetu"
                                        value={dataOne.shubetu || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange} />
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>ライセンス</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        type="text"
                                        name="licenseManage"
                                        value={dataOne.licenseManage || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange} />
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Form.Row>
                            <Form.Row>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>用途</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        type="text"
                                        name="youto"
                                        value={dataOne.youto || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange} />
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>備考</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        type="text"
                                        name="bikou"
                                        value={dataOne.bikou || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange} />
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Form.Row>
                            <Form.Row>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>承認者</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        type="text"
                                        name="authorizer"
                                        value={dataOne.authorizer || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange} />
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>承認日</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        type="text"
                                        name="approvalDate"
                                        value={dataOne.approvalDate || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange} />
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Form.Row>
                            <Form.Row>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>URL</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        type="text"
                                        name="url"
                                        value={dataOne.url || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange} />
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Form.Row>
                        </Card.Body>
                        <Card.Footer style={{ "textAlign": "right" }}>
                            <Link to="/">
                                <Button size="sm" variant="outline-primary" type="button">
                                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} />トップ
                                </Button>
                            </Link>
                            <Button size="sm" variant="outline-success" type="submit" style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }} >
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faClipboardCheck} /> 編集完了
                            </Button>

                        </Card.Footer>
                    </Form>
                </Card>

            </div>
            <Box pt={4} pb={4}>
                <Copyright />
            </Box>
        </div>

    )
}
```

Add react-bootstrap validation

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Card, Form, Button, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import { Copyright } from './Copyright';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faList, faHome, faClipboardCheck } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

export const EditData = (props) => {

    const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);//Add
    const history = useHistory()
    const id = props.listNo;
    const [dataOne, setDataOne] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:8080/action/edit/" + id).then((response) =>
            setDataOne(response.data)
        )
    }, [])

    const handleChange = event => {
        setDataOne({ ...dataOne, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    };

    const handleSubmit = event => {

        //Add and Change code
        const form = event.currentTarget;
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            setValidated(true);
        } else {

            const list = {
                listNo: dataOne.listNo,
                softwareName: dataOne.softwareName,
                saiyouDate: dataOne.saiyouDate,
                version: dataOne.version,
                shubetu: dataOne.shubetu,
                licenseManage: dataOne.licenseManage,
                youto: dataOne.youto,
                bikou: dataOne.bikou,
                authorizer: dataOne.authorizer,
                approvalDate: dataOne.approvalDate,
                url: dataOne.url
            }

            axios.post("http://localhost:8080/action/edit/contents", list)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.data != null) {
                        alert('編集完了！')
                        window.setTimeout(() => {
                            history.push("/")
                        }, 1000)
                    }
                })

        }





    };



    return (
        <div>

            <div className="container">
                <Card>
                    <Card.Header className="text-center" style={{ backgroundColor: '#75A9FF', color: '#FFF' }}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faList} />使用許可ソフトウェアリスト
                    </Card.Header>
                    {// add novalidate and required
                    }
                    <Form id="listFormId" noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                        <Form.Control
                            required
                            type="hidden"
                            name="listNo"
                            value={dataOne.listNo || ""}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />

                        <Card.Body>
                            <Form.Row>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>ソフトウェア名</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        required
                                        type="text"
                                        name="softwareName"
                                        value={dataOne.softwareName || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                    />
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Form.Row>
                            <Form.Row>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>採用日</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        required
                                        type="text"
                                        name="saiyouDate"
                                        value={dataOne.saiyouDate || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange} />
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>バージョン</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        required
                                        type="text"
                                        name="version"
                                        value={dataOne.version || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                    />
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Form.Row>
                            <Form.Row>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>種別</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        required
                                        type="text"
                                        name="shubetu"
                                        value={dataOne.shubetu || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange} />
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>ライセンス</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        required
                                        type="text"
                                        name="licenseManage"
                                        value={dataOne.licenseManage || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange} />
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Form.Row>
                            <Form.Row>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>用途</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        required
                                        type="text"
                                        name="youto"
                                        value={dataOne.youto || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange} />
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>備考</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        type="text"
                                        name="bikou"
                                        value={dataOne.bikou || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange} />
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Form.Row>
                            <Form.Row>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>承認者</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        required
                                        type="text"
                                        name="authorizer"
                                        value={dataOne.authorizer || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange} />
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>承認日</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        required
                                        type="text"
                                        name="approvalDate"
                                        value={dataOne.approvalDate || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange} />
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Form.Row>
                            <Form.Row>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    <Form.Label>URL</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control
                                        required
                                        type="text"
                                        name="url"
                                        value={dataOne.url || ""}
                                        onChange={handleChange} />
                                </Form.Group>
                            </Form.Row>
                        </Card.Body>
                        <Card.Footer style={{ "textAlign": "right" }}>
                            <Link to="/">
                                <Button size="sm" variant="outline-primary" type="button">
                                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} />トップ
                                </Button>
                            </Link>
                            <Button size="sm" variant="outline-success" type="submit" style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }} >
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faClipboardCheck} /> 編集完了
                            </Button>

                        </Card.Footer>
                    </Form>
                </Card>

            </div>
            <Box pt={4} pb={4}>
                <Copyright />
            </Box>
        </div>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that Error in the following way.
I wrote event.preventDefault(); outside if statement like that.

```
event.preventDefault();

        //Add and Change code
        const form = event.currentTarget;
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            setValidated(true);
        } else {
```